# Convert Mouse Points to Quadratic BSplines

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm writing a drawing program.  I'm trying to take an ordered list mouse positions, and approximate a smooth Quadratic BSpline Curve.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know what I'm doing, my control points look like
[prev] - [center] - [next]
The prev and next should stay co-linear but they can be different distances from center.  I'm fairly flexible on this since converting wont be hard.

Comment: If they are mouse clicks anyway, then why is it that you have to worry about distance from center? Just pick your mouse click coordinates in your "2d world" and draw the bspline right there.  (I am guessing that you are interested in 2d ortho world)

Comment: You are right, I am interested in 2d ortho world.  I should have been more clear, the ordered list of mouse positions is all the mouse positions while it's down.  So I need to throw out some, use some as control points, and add a few extra control points to make the curve approximately match.

Comment: ok, But again centering shouldn't be an issue. I am not clear what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["B-spline curve fitting based on adaptive curve refinement using dominant points" by Park & Lee](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1244878) and ["Fair interpolation and approximation of B-splines by energy minimization and points insertion" by Vassilev](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TYR-3VTJGFP-8&_user=10&_coverDate=09%2F30%2F1996&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1406265730&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=e671fe6bc2690aa5c336e5607ceca57b) seem to be solving this problem. Also there look like a few references on the first link that should help you.

Converting data points to control points in areas of high curvature and removing data points in areas of little curvature is a general approach.

Comment: GJ. It was interesting question.

Comment: I appreciate the articles, but to anyone working on this I recommend you go deeper into the topics of these articles.  They're a high level combination of old methods, I'd start simpler...